# Open maps failing separation axioms

Tags: general-topology

Can one give an example of a surjective open mapping between topological spaces with domain satisfying the $T_0$ separation axiom, whose range is not $T_0$? Similarly, for $T_2$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the mapping $f : \mathbb{R} \to \{ 0 , 1\}$ defined by $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if }x\text{ is rational} \\
1, &\text{if }x\text{ is irrational.}
\end{cases}$$
Find a non-T$_0$-topology on $\{0,1\}$ for which $f$ is a continuous open surjection.

Comment: Can we make something similar for cts closed maps?

Comment: @bran: T$_1$-ness and normality are preserved by continuous closed surjections.  The other (common) separation axioms are not so preserved.  (For T$_{3\,1/2}$, T$_3$ and T$_2$, take a non-normal T$_{3\,1/2}$-space $X$ (such as the Niemytzki (or Moore) plane, two disjoint closed $E , F \subseteq X$ which cannot be separated by open sets, and define $Y$ to be the space obtained by identifying all points of $E$ to a point, and all points of $F$ to a point.  Then $Y$ is not Hausdorff, but the quotient mapping $X \to Y$ is a closed continuous surjection.)