# Closed image of $T_0$-space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, $X$ is $T_0$ and suppose $f\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous closed surjection. Must $Y$ be $T_0$?

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $V_n=\{k\in\Bbb N:k<n\}$, and let $\tau=\{\Bbb N\}\cup\{V_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$; then $\langle\Bbb N,\tau\rangle$ is a $T_0$-space. Take it as your $X$, and let $Y$ be the two-point space with the indiscrete topology. Can you find a surjection $f:\Bbb N\to Y$ that is continuous and closed, something a bit similar to [Arthur Fischer’s example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/389621/12042) in his answer to your previous question?